# Can you register two cron events in a single function?

Tags: wp-cron, cron

Take the following:

```
public static function activate() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', 'process_rss_items' );
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minute_15', 'process_top_news' );
} // end activate
```

This is stored in a singleton class. I'm calling the following right outside of the class:

```
// add once 15 minute interval to wp schedules
function new_interval($interval) {

    $interval['minutes_15'] = array('interval' => 15*60, 'display' => 'Once every 15 minutes');

    return $interval;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'new_interval');
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'MyClassName', 'activate' ) );
```

WordPress seems to only be acknowledging the first event and not the second one. Is it because it's a custom cron schedule?

Might be a bug, just wondering if anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: What happens if you make the `new_interval()` a method of your class and call the filter inside your activation hook ( above the cron registrations ) `add_filter('cron_schedules', array( $this, 'new_interval' ) );`?

Comment: Good call. Believe I may have overlooked that simple fact! :-X  I'll try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Howdy_McGee pinpointed the issue in a comment on the original question:

> Make the `new_interval()` a method of your class and call the filter
>   inside your activation hook (above the cron registrations):
>
> `add_filter('cron_schedules', array( $this, 'new_interval' ) );`